# Angular 2 strange error after uploading dist folder

Tags: angular, angular2-cli

My app worked great so far, I've been working on few updates and then I uploaded my new generated dist folder to my website.

Suddenly I get this error: `main.5b5a7be….bundle.js:31 Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list`

Now different error appeared:

```
main.8d6ae5a….bundle.js:42 Uncaught TypeError: i.QueueScheduler is not a constructor
```

What's wrong? How I can detect where this error comes from?

Answer (score 0):

Error "SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list" itself explained that you have missed ending closing brackets `)` for your `QueueScheduler` constructor or for other function after setting arguments.

Comment: I haven't used QueueScheduler in my app